# Some string in substring

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT 'Name','Artists','Release_date','Popularity','Duration'
UNION 
(SELECT name, artists, RIGHT(release_date, 4) AS year, popularity, SUBSTRING(sec_to_time(floor(duration_ms/1000)), 4, 5) as time
FROM lt.ltdataset
WHERE RIGHT(release_date, 4) > 2020 AND danceability > 0.5
ORDER BY popularity DESC
LIMIT 50)
INTO OUTFILE '---------'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Hello everyone, in result 'duration' I get MM:SS
But how to make result MM min SS s like 00 min 00 s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that yolu can use SUBSTRING_INDEX with CONCAT

```
SELECT 'Name','Artists','Release_date','Popularity','Duration'
UNION 
SELECT name, artists, RIGHT(release_date, 4) AS year, popularity, CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(sec_to_time(floor(99000/1000)), 4, 5),':',1),' min ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(sec_to_time(floor(99000/1000)), 4, 5),':',-1),' s') as time
FROM lt.ltdataset
WHERE RIGHT(release_date, 4) > 2020 AND danceability > 0.5
ORDER BY popularity DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Thanks. But how reverse 'release_date'? now DD:MM:YYYY I need YYYY:MM:DD 
release_date text type

Comment: substring_index works the also in that case, you have to test it in a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e9661cbe45d7daeca9b7f10bd56f65c

Comment: yes, this now I learned, but I need reverse all column dates. Like from 02/01/2021 to 2021-01-02

Comment: like before concat the values in the order you need https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5057b523b41434a23ba41220cad79912 , you still have to test if there is only 2004

Comment: In date column not all equal date, every date different, and cant be the same always

Comment: if they are not all equal you need a function to check  the content and then build the wanted date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235739/discussion-between-martynas-saka-and-nbk).